# Triggers for many rows at once

Tags: mysql, triggers

So I have these three tables. The orders table is list of orders existed, while the order details consist of items that is in an order (because 1 order can have more than one catalog).

Cust_order

| Order_id | Name | Email | Shipping_Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bryan | bryan@gmail.com | Shiped |

Order_item

| Od_id | Order_id | Catalog_id | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 2. | 1 | 2 | 5 |

Inventory

| Catalog_id | quantityInStock |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 10 |

I want to create a trigger that if the shipping_status in orders table is 'shipped', then it will update the stock in inventory.

I've created this trigger

```
create trigger update_inventory
after update on cust_order
for each row 
begin
if new.shipping_status="Shipped" then
update inventory 
set inStock = inStock - (select quantity from order_item where order_id=new.order_id)
where catalog_id in (select catalog_id from order_item where order_id=new.order_id);
end if;
end;
//
```

But it doesn't work and turns #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

How to create trigger that updates multiple row at once?

Comment: *Is it possible to create trigger that updates for many catalog at once?* Yes, this is possible.

Comment: Please note that storing the shipping status in the order table makes it hard to implement partial deliveries.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: Please post your table schema and sample dat.

Comment: I’ve editted the questio